# Pause a function in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop this function for a few seconds while adding every digit, 
but this function doesn't work as intended.

```js
function yazmaeffetkti() {
  var cumleler = ["salam necesen", "yaxsiyam sen "]
  currentcumle = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < cumleler.length; i++) {
    cumle = cumleler[i]
    for (var z = 0; z < cumle.length; z++) {
      currentcumle += cumle[z]

      function stateChange(currentcumle) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(currentcumle);
        }, 3000);
      }
      stateChange(currentcumle)
    }
    currentcumle = ""
  }
}

yazmaeffetkti()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way to achieve that is to use `async` and `await`:

```js
async function yazmaeffetkti() {
    // ...
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    console.log(currentcumle);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my version:

```js
async function yazmaeffetkti() {
  var cumleler = ["salam necesen", "yaxsiyam sen "]
  currentcumle = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < cumleler.length; i++) {
    cumle = cumleler[i]
    for (var z = 0; z < cumle.length; z++) {
      currentcumle += cumle[z]
      await stateChange(currentcumle)
    }
    currentcumle = ""
  }
}

var stateChange = (currentcumle) => new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(currentcumle);
          resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
  });

yazmaeffetkti()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Robo Robok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048175/5784924), here is an example using the same concept but with `then` instead of `async/await`. I personnaly prefer it but it's up to you.

```js
function yazmaeffetkti() {
  var cumleler = ["salam necesen", "yaxsiyam sen "]
  currentcumle = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < cumleler.length; i++) {
    cumle = cumleler[i]
    for (var z = 0; z < cumle.length; z++) {
      currentcumle += cumle[z]
      new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)).then(() => {
        console.log(currentcumle);
      });
    }
    currentcumle = ""
  }
}

yazmaeffetkti()
```